# UIActivityViewController not working with latest ios 17.2

Tags: ios, swift

I have about 40 ipad minis of various ages running an app I developed managed on an mdm.  We are upgrading devices so I recently bought 4 ipad mini v6 in December.  Everything appears to work except printing.  Printing does work via Notes so I think its something with xcode.  The user can swipe on a component to print a barcode to a Brother barcode printer.  Again, I can print to this computer using Notes.  On any of the other 38 older ipad minis, a AirDrop dialog appears like this. [image]. but on the new devices it doesn't work and looks like this [image] see the empty bar at the top of the screen.  Here is the relevant code.  I think it must have something to do with UIActivityViewController.  This code works fine on the older devices but not on the newest ones.

```
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 1000, height: 400))
        let BarcodeImg = renderer.image { ctx in

            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.alignment = .center

            let attrs: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
                .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 65),
                .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle
            ]
            
            let myQRCode = generateBarcode(from: self.qrCodeLabel.text!)
            myQRCode?.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 15, y: 60))
            
            
            let string = self.qrCodeLabel.text!
            let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes: attrs)
            attributedString.draw(with: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 1000, height: 400), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)
            
        }
        qrCodeImage.image = BarcodeImg
        
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width
        let screenHeight = screenSize.height
        
        let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [BarcodeImg], applicationActivities: [])
        let popover = vc.popoverPresentationController
        popover?.sourceView = view
        popover?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 32, y: 32, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
        present(vc, animated: true)
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas what is causing this or how to troubleshoot the issue.

UPDATE

I received a replacement ipad mini from apple with ios 17.2 which I manually installed the app onto ipad (using developer account list not my mdm) after making the code change.

```
popover?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: 32, width: 0, height: 0)
```

Now, it does create the AirDrop popup with a printer selection.  And, I was able to print to the desired printer.  However, it also generates all this in the xcode console.

fopen failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory)
Errors found! Invalidating cache...
Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.primitiveattribute AND originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.frontboard AND target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.trustedtarget AND Target not hosted by originator)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=(originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.primitiveattribute AND originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.frontboard AND target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.trustedtarget AND Target not hosted by originator)}>
(501) personaAttributesForPersonaType for type:0 failed with error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.mobile.usermanagerd.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 159 - Sandbox restriction." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.mobile.usermanagerd.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 159 - Sandbox restriction.}
Received port for identifier response: <(null)> with error:Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "Client not entitled" UserInfo={RBSEntitlement=com.apple.runningboard.process-state, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Client not entitled, RBSPermanent=false}
elapsedCPUTimeForFrontBoard couldn't generate a task port
Received port for identifier response: <(null)> with error:Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "Client not entitled" UserInfo={RBSEntitlement=com.apple.runningboard.process-state, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Client not entitled, RBSPermanent=false}
elapsedCPUTimeForFrontBoard couldn't generate a task port
Failed to create 0x88 image slot (alpha=1 wide=1) (client=0x5c8de949) [0x5 (os/kern) failure]
<0x101c10b10> Gesture: System gesture gate timed out.
Received port for identifier response: <(null)> with error:Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "Client not entitled" UserInfo={RBSEntitlement=com.apple.runningboard.process-state, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Client not entitled, RBSPermanent=false}
elapsedCPUTimeForFrontBoard couldn't generate a task port
LPLinkMetadata: Failed to decode with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "value for key 'root' was of unexpected class 'LPPlaceholderLinkMetadata' (0x1de8b3e38) [/System/Library/Frameworks/LinkPresentation.framework].
Allowed classes are:
{(
"'LPLinkMetadata' (0x1dd89e3d8) [/System/Library/Frameworks/LinkPresentation.framework]",
"'NSNull' (0x1dd678298) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]"
)}" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=value for key 'root' was of unexpected class 'LPPlaceholderLinkMetadata' (0x1de8b3e38) [/System/Library/Frameworks/LinkPresentation.framework].
Allowed classes are:
{(
"'LPLinkMetadata' (0x1dd89e3d8) [/System/Library/Frameworks/LinkPresentation.framework]",
"'NSNull' (0x1dd678298) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]"
)}}
LPLinkMetadata: Failed to decode with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "value for key 'root' was of unexpected class 'LPPlaceholderLinkMetadata' (0x1de8b3e38) [/System/Library/Frameworks/LinkPresentation.framework].
Allowed classes are:
{(
"'LPLinkMetadata' (0x1dd89e3d8) [/System/Library/Frameworks/LinkPresentation.framework]",
"'NSNull' (0x1dd678298) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]"
)}" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=value for key 'root' was of unexpected class 'LPPlaceholderLinkMetadata' (0x1de8b3e38) [/System/Library/Frameworks/LinkPresentation.framework].
Allowed classes are:
{(
"'LPLinkMetadata' (0x1dd89e3d8) [/System/Library/Frameworks/LinkPresentation.framework]",
"'NSNull' (0x1dd678298) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]"
)}}

Comment: Don't post photos of the screen. Take a proper screenshot as PNG, crop it, and include it in the question.

Comment: ok sorry about that its not easy to get screenshots off these ipads

Comment: The sourceRect seems quit big. Not sure it is necessary if you have a source view to indicate to the popover where to point to.

Comment: `sourceRect` is obviously completely wrong. Normally you just put the button there as `view` and its `bounds` as `sourceRect`.

Comment: I can redefine sourceRect as follows, which runs ok on older device.  will try it on new device:  popover?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: 32, width: 0, height: 0)

Comment: Your new source rect is as silly as the old one. Just do what Sulthan said. Anyway there is no remaining issue related to your original question.

Comment: That change is from the popoverPresentationController documentation.  Please provide a code example of this comment:  put the button there as view and its bounds as sourceRect